# Custom UIActivity fails to display activityViewController contained in navController on iOS8 device

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, ios8, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have a custom UIActivity that displays a View Controller within a Navigation Controller.  It works fine in iOS7, but on an iOS 8 device it fails to load the view or call the UIActivityViewController completion handler.  Here is the setup of the ActivityViewController

```
UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[someString] applicationActivities:@[myCustomActivity]];
activityController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypePostToFacebook];

[activityController setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed){
    NSLog(@"I'm not getting called");
}];
```

I'm skipping over the presentation - it's done in a UIPopoverController for the iPad, and modally for the iPhone.  It works fine for all of the default actions.

The problem occurs when I select the custom activity from the ActivityController.  All that happens is the ActivityController dismisses.  Here is what is going on in my UIActivity concrete class:

First, I allocate a viewController in prepareWithActivityItems.

```
- (void)prepareWithActivityItems:(NSArray *)activityItems
{
for (id item in activityItems) {
    if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {

        UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
        vc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 500);
        [vc.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
        self.controller = navController;

        break;
    }
}
}
```

This gets called correctly and stores the controller in a strongly typed property called controller.

Next, I've defined activityViewController in this class as follows:

```
- (UIViewController *)activityViewController
{
    return self.controller;
}
```

setting a breakpoint there, I can see this gets called, and at the time self.controller still has a valid navigation controller with a viewController in the stack.

According to the doc, this is what should happen:

> Subclasses that provide additional UI using a view controller can
>   override this method to return that view controller. If this method
>   returns a valid object, the system presents the returned view
>   controller modally instead of calling the performActivity method.

But that isn't happening here.  My UIPopoverController containing the ActivityViewController gets dismissed, but the viewController returned by activityViewController does not get presented.  Further, the completion handler for the UIActivityViewController doesn't get called.  It seems to completely silently fail.

I'm at a loss here, because I don't see any good way to debug this further with the presentation of this controller being black box.  I definitely don't see it in the view hierarchy after it should have been presented, and for that matter viewDidLoad is never triggered on the activityViewController.

To clarify, I'm trying to get this to work via XC5 / iOS7 SDK but running on an iOS8 device.  And by the way, I was surprised it worked, but XC5 is able to run debug builds on an iOS8 RC device.